# SCAP - Workbench on MAC (with Remote Machine option) - Failed to create SSH master socket

Tags: openscap

**I'm running latest workbench**:

`SCAP Workbench 1.2.1, compiled with Qt 5.13.2, using OpenSCAP 1.4.0`

I can't run a scan on remote server using RHEL7 (DISA STIG profile - or any profile) because of a socket error ... anyone else have this issue?

Can't connect to remote machine! Exception was: `There was a problem with SshConnection! Failed to create SSH master socket!`

***Diagnostic info**:

```
Starting process '/usr/bin/ssh -M -f -N -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ControlPath=/private/var/folders/k_/kg_8n79x5z54fk4fln24j10r0000gn/T/scap-workbench-wJhTVS/ssh_socket -p 22 maintuser@aws' Starting process '/usr/bin/ssh -M -f -N -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ControlPath=/private/var/folders/k_/kg_8n79x5z54fk4fln24j10r0000gn/T/scap-workbench-wJhTVS/ssh_socket -p 22 maintuser@aws' stdout: =============================== stderr: =============================== unix_listener: path "/private/var/folders/k_/kg_8n79x5z54fk4fln24j10r0000gn/T/scap-workbench-wJhTVS/ssh_socket.Mw5tqcJq4uuoTEAg" too long for Unix domain socket
```

So it seems that the length of the string in the ControlPath is too long.

I wonder if there is a way to control that value?  Anyone have this issue?   I've tried on both my Macs and have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix on GitHub ...

https://github.com/OpenSCAP/scap-workbench/issues/254

> TMPDIR=/tmp; open /Applications/scap-workbench.app